Is the rust on this shower drain normal?
Is the rust on the shower drain normal?
I'm not too savvy when it comes to plumbing, is the rust on this drain concerning? I wiped it down and it feels pretty solid so hoping nothing here requires replacing, since budget is tight and I believe this would require replacing the entire shower?
I believe the rust is due to the steel screws on the drain cover the builder used, since another unit also has the same rust.
Additionally, the screw holes are pretty stripped. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix that? I was thinking either using a slightly larger screw since the hole is too small for a plastic anchor to fit.

Yep. That's legacy cast iron, and it rusts. It also accumulates hard deposits on the inside, which can eventually restrict flow severely. Whenever you have the opportunity, replace it with modern plastic pipe.
One strategy for the screw holes is to drill and tap for a larger diameter. If they're too far gone, drill to a common plastic hollow wall plug size and use those.

Thanks for the insight, do you think it would be okay to let it be for the time being while being diligent about cleaning deposits? Don't have the budget for a shower remodel anytime soon unfortunately. And good call for the screw holes I'm going to try that

That depends entirely on how it flows. I wouldn't do much of anything until it shows signs of clogging. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.
